# A Macro for Building a Linked List

Tags: c++, g++, c-preprocessor

I am programmatically generating C++ code. Frequently I have to output linked lists of the following form,

```
PTR(new List(a,PTR(new List(NULL,NULL))))
PTR(new List(a, PTR(new List(b,PTR(new List(NULL,NULL))))))
```

As the size of the lists grow generated code gets uglier I was wondering is it possible to define a variadic macro of the form,

```
LIST(a)
LIST(a,b)
```

That would expand to code in the first form.

Comment: Yes, and Boost.Preprocessor is a great start.

Comment: @chris, can you point me to an article that shows how I can do that? This for an embedded platform I would rather not depend on boost for a single macro.

Comment: You can certainly use Boost.PP without the rest of Boost. And it's all macros, so there's no code besides what you generate.

Comment: Using macros is counter-productive. It's absolutely not smart to use these macros. Simply by not using macros you *avoid* the problem you're into here. Using linked lists is likewise generally counter-productive. There are however some few situations where they're warranted. What do they represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's [one way](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/60def59e0e2ff39c) using Boost.Preprocessor, which doesn't depend on any other part of Boost:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>

#define FOR_EACH_OP(r, data, elem) PTR(new List(elem,
#define DOUBLE_RPAREN(...) ))

#define LIST(...) LIST_I(BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__))
#define LIST_I(seq) \
    BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(FOR_EACH_OP, /*empty*/, seq) \
    PTR(new List(NULL,NULL)) \
    BOOST_PP_REPEAT(BOOST_PP_SEQ_SIZE(seq), DOUBLE_RPAREN, /*empty*/)

LIST(a) // PTR(new List(a, PTR(new List(NULL,NULL)) ))
LIST(a,b) // PTR(new List(a, PTR(new List(b, PTR(new List(NULL,NULL)) )) ))
```

`LIST` simply turns the arguments into a "PP sequence", which provides a convenient `FOR_EACH`. For each argument, the left part is built up. Then the `NULL` part is added. Finally, matching right parentheses are added according to how many arguments were given.

Disclaimer: `LIST()` will not work as expected due to that being a call with one (empty) argument.

---

If you're really allergic to Boost, you can [make simplified versions of these](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b082d541fc4e4617). For example, one way to support up to four arguments:

```
#define CAT(_0, _1) CAT_I(_0, _1)
#define CAT_I(_0, _1) _0##_1

#define ARG5(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, ...) _4
#define NARGS(...) ARG5(__VA_ARGS__, 4, 3, 2, 1,)
#define OVERLOAD(prefix, ...) CAT(prefix, NARGS(__VA_ARGS__))

#define ELEM(i, ...) CAT(ELEM_, i)(__VA_ARGS__,)
#define ELEM_0(_0, ...) _0
#define ELEM_1(_0, _1, ...) _1
#define ELEM_2(_0, _1, _2, ...) _2
#define ELEM_3(_0, _1, _2, _3, ...) _3

#define FOR_EACH(macro, ...) OVERLOAD(FOR_EACH_, __VA_ARGS__)(macro, __VA_ARGS__)
#define FOR_EACH_1(macro, ...) macro(ELEM(0, __VA_ARGS__))
#define FOR_EACH_2(macro, ...) FOR_EACH_1(macro, __VA_ARGS__) macro(ELEM(1, __VA_ARGS__))
#define FOR_EACH_3(macro, ...) FOR_EACH_2(macro, __VA_ARGS__) macro(ELEM(2, __VA_ARGS__))
#define FOR_EACH_4(macro, ...) FOR_EACH_3(macro, __VA_ARGS__) macro(ELEM(3, __VA_ARGS__))

#define REPEAT(n, macro) CAT(REPEAT_, n)(macro)
#define REPEAT_1(macro) macro()
#define REPEAT_2(macro) REPEAT_1(macro) macro()
#define REPEAT_3(macro) REPEAT_2(macro) macro()
#define REPEAT_4(macro) REPEAT_3(macro) macro()

#define FOR_EACH_MACRO(elem) PTR(new List(elem,
#define DOUBLE_RPAREN() ))

#define LIST(...) LIST_I(NARGS(__VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__)
#define LIST_I(n, ...) \
    FOR_EACH(FOR_EACH_MACRO, __VA_ARGS__) \
    PTR(new List(NULL,NULL)) \
    REPEAT(n, DOUBLE_RPAREN)

LIST(a) // PTR(new List(a, PTR(new List(NULL,NULL)) ))
LIST(a,b) // PTR(new List(a, PTR(new List(b, PTR(new List(NULL,NULL)) )) ))
```